# Specified 'redis' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded

Tags: actioncable, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to push my application to production which is using action cable. every time i push it gives me an error saying:

```
ERROR -- Specified 'redis' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'redis'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by Action Cable).: nil
```

My Gem file is like:

```
group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
 gem 'web-console', '~> 3.0'
 gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
 gem 'em-hiredis'
 gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
end
```

and My Cable.yml is like:

```
production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

development:
  adapter: async

test:
  adapter: async
```

How should i fix it and make my action cable work on develop.

Gemlock whole:
This is gem file and redis is specified as `redis (~> 3.0)`

```
GEM
    remote: https://rubygems.org/
    specs:
      actioncable (5.0.6)
        actionpack (= 5.0.6)
        nio4r (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
        websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
      actionmailer (5.0.6)
        actionpack (= 5.0.6)
        actionview (= 5.0.6)
        activejob (= 5.0.6)
        mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
        rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      actionpack (5.0.6)
        actionview (= 5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        rack (~> 2.0)
        rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
        rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
        rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      actionview (5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        builder (~> 3.1)
        erubis (~> 2.7.0)
        rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
        rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
      activejob (5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        globalid (>= 0.3.6)
      activemodel (5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
      activerecord (5.0.6)
        activemodel (= 5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        arel (~> 7.0)
      activesupport (5.0.6)
        concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
        i18n (~> 0.7)
        minitest (~> 5.1)
        tzinfo (~> 1.1)
      arel (7.1.4)
      bcrypt (3.1.11)
      bindex (0.5.0)
      builder (3.2.3)
      byebug (9.1.0)
      coderay (1.1.2)
      coffee-rails (4.1.1)
        coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
        railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
      coffee-script (2.4.1)
        coffee-script-source
        execjs
      coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
      concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
      crass (1.0.2)
      devise (4.3.0)
        bcrypt (~> 3.0)
        orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
        railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.2)
        responders
        warden (~> 1.2.3)
      em-hiredis (0.3.1)
        eventmachine (~> 1.0)
        hiredis (~> 0.6.0)
      erubis (2.7.0)
      eventmachine (1.2.5)
      execjs (2.7.0)
      ffi (1.9.18)
      globalid (0.4.1)
        activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      hiredis (0.6.1)
      i18n (0.9.1)
        concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      jbuilder (2.7.0)
        activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
        multi_json (>= 1.2)
      jquery-rails (4.3.1)
        rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
        railties (>= 4.2.0)
        thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      listen (3.0.8)
        rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
        rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      loofah (2.1.1)
        crass (~> 1.0.2)
        nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
      mail (2.7.0)
        mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
      method_source (0.9.0)
      mini_mime (0.1.4)
      mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
      minitest (5.10.3)
      multi_json (1.12.2)
      nio4r (2.1.0)
      nokogiri (1.8.1)
        mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
      orm_adapter (0.5.0)
      pg (0.21.0)
      pry (0.11.2)
        coderay (~> 1.1.0)
        method_source (~> 0.9.0)
      pry-byebug (3.5.0)
        byebug (~> 9.1)
        pry (~> 0.10)
      puma (3.10.0)
      rack (2.0.3)
      rack-test (0.6.3)
        rack (>= 1.0)
      rails (5.0.6)
        actioncable (= 5.0.6)
        actionmailer (= 5.0.6)
        actionpack (= 5.0.6)
        actionview (= 5.0.6)
        activejob (= 5.0.6)
        activemodel (= 5.0.6)
        activerecord (= 5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        bundler (>= 1.3.0)
        railties (= 5.0.6)
        sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
      rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
        activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
        nokogiri (>= 1.6)
      rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
        loofah (~> 2.0)
      railties (5.0.6)
        actionpack (= 5.0.6)
        activesupport (= 5.0.6)
        method_source
        rake (>= 0.8.7)
        thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
      rake (12.2.1)
      rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
      rb-inotify (0.9.10)
        ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
      redis (3.3.5)
      responders (2.4.0)
        actionpack (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
        railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.3)
      sass (3.5.3)
        sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
      sass-listen (4.0.0)
        rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
        rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      sass-rails (5.0.6)
        railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
        sass (~> 3.1)
        sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
        sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
        tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
      semantic-ui-sass (2.2.12.0)
        sass (>= 3.2)
      slim (3.0.8)
        temple (>= 0.7.6, < 0.9)
        tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
      slim-rails (3.1.3)
        actionpack (>= 3.1)
        railties (>= 3.1)
        slim (~> 3.0)
      spring (2.0.2)
        activesupport (>= 4.2)
      spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
        listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
        spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
      sprockets (3.7.1)
        concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
        rack (> 1, < 3)
      sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
        actionpack (>= 4.0)
        activesupport (>= 4.0)
        sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
      temple (0.8.0)
      thor (0.20.0)
      thread_safe (0.3.6)
      tilt (2.0.8)
      turbolinks (5.0.1)
        turbolinks-source (~> 5)
      turbolinks-source (5.0.3)
      tzinfo (1.2.4)
        thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      uglifier (3.2.0)
        execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
      warden (1.2.7)
        rack (>= 1.0)
      web-console (3.5.1)
        actionview (>= 5.0)
        activemodel (>= 5.0)
        bindex (>= 0.4.0)
        railties (>= 5.0)
      websocket-driver (0.6.5)
        websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
      websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

  PLATFORMS
    ruby

  DEPENDENCIES
    byebug
    coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
    devise
    em-hiredis
    jbuilder (~> 2.0)
    jquery-rails
    listen (~> 3.0.5)
    pg
    pry-byebug
    puma
    rails (>= 5.0.0.beta3, < 5.1)
    redis (~> 3.0)
    sass-rails (~> 5.0)
    semantic-ui-sass
    slim-rails
    spring
    spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
    turbolinks (~> 5.x)
    tzinfo-data
    uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
    web-console (~> 3.0)

  BUNDLED WITH
     1.16.0
```

Comment: Do you have any other version of the gem specified in your project?, what's on your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock - complete files.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma you want whole gem and gem.lock file ?

Comment: @SebastiánPalma other version of gem for redis ? i just have redits gem identified in development only

Comment: Yes, whole files, maybe the Gemfile.lock is specifying any other version.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma Attached

Comment: You're Gemfile.lock has `redis (3.3.5)`, try deleting the Gemfile.lock and running bundle again.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma i tried that and it didnt help. facing the same issue! on local action cabel works fine, it only happens when i push to heroku and says `There was an exception - Gem::LoadError(Specified 'redis' for Action Cable pubsub adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'redis'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by Action Cable).)`

Comment: do i have to add my heroku app url in production url: ? 
`url: redis://localhost:6379/1` here in production

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30527).

Comment: Downgrade redis back to version 3.3.5. You can see it follow the url: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30527

Answer (score 3):

I see two separate issues:

1. In your gemfile you are specifying the redis gem for only the development environment. Make sure to take the line `gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'` and put it outside the `group :development` block. That way it will be included in the production gems.
2. Your redis URL is pointing to localhost for production. That will not work, you will need to point it to a redis url that is available remotely. If you are using Heroku, you can use the [redis add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-redis).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. 
I solved it by updating my **gems** via (`bundle update`). Not sure which **gem** exactly solved it.

Now I have: `ruby 2.5.0`, `rails 5.1.5`, `redis 4.0.1`, `actioncable 5.1.5`.

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this issue was in the Gemfile

```
gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
```

And follow this deploy guide to heroku:

https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable#deploying-our-application-to-heroku